# Odoo 10 - Retrieve image from product_template

Tags: odoo-10, odoo

I am trying to get the image of a given product in Odoo 10.

Specifically, I want to retrieve the image object from a product_template record in order to copy it to another product_template record.

I have tried the following code without success:

```
self.env['product.template'].search([('id', '=', product_id)]).image
```

How could I retrieve the image once I have the product_template record instance?

Odoo 10 community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In odoo v10 I think the image field name is image_medium. You need to write the statement as like this:
`self.env['product.template'].search([('id', '=', product_id)]).image_medium`
For reference you can check this method in product.product model.
`def _compute_images()`.